# CakePHP 3.4: query where or matching

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I read the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html), but I can not figure out how to combine in a single query a `matching()` and a `orWhere()`.

Example: I have `Photo` that belongs from `Album`. Both have the `active` field. So I'm trying to write a `findInactive()` method. A "inactive" photo has the `active` field as `false` **or** matching an album that has the `active` fields as `false`.

Something like this:

```
public function findInactive(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query->matching('Albums', function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['Albums.active' => false]);
        })
        ->orWhere(['Photos.active' => false])
        ->enableAutoFields(true);

    return $query;
}
```

But that does not work:

```
'SELECT [...] FROM photos Photos INNER JOIN photos_albums Albums ON (Albums.active = :c0 AND Albums.id = (Photos.album_id)) WHERE Photos.active = :c1'
```

How to do? Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Maybe a possible solution is use`contain()`:

```
    $query->contain(['Albums => ['fields' => ['active']]])
        ->where(['Photos.active' => false])
        ->orWhere(['Albums.active' => false]);
```

But is it not possible to use `matching()` or `innerJoinWith()`?

Comment: If a `Photo` **belongsTo** `Album` then your last solution seems the simplest one. The contain creates the JOIN. I don't see the need to use other solution

Answer (score 2):

### Add the conditions to the main query

`matching()` or `innerJoinWith()` with conditions is the wrong way to go, as the conditions are being addded to the `INNER` joins `ON` clause, which will cause the `Photo` row to be excluded in case the `Albums.active` condition doesn't match.

If you want to only receive photos that belong to an album, then you want to use `matching()` or `innerJoinWith()`, but you'll have to add the conditions to the main query instead, ie:

```
$query
   ->innerJoinWith('Albums')
   ->where(['Albums.active' => false])
   ->orWhere(['Photos.active' => false])
   // ...
```

In case a photo doesn't have to belong to an album, or it's not important whether it does, you could use either `leftJoin()`, `leftJoinWith()`, or even `contain()`.

The latter however may use the `INNER` `joinStrategy` and/or the `select` `strategy` (which uses a separate query), so you'd need to take care of ensuring that it uses `LEFT` and `join` instead. Using containments however is usually only advised if you actually want to contain something, and given that your finder seems to be supposed to just filter things, I'd say go with `leftJoinWith()` instead:

```
$query
   ->leftJoinWith('Albums')
   ->where(['Albums.active' => false])
   ->orWhere(['Photos.active' => false])
   // ...
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Filtering by Associated Data Via Matching And Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Retrieving Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsTo Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)**